# How are async NSURLConnections handled when the viewController changes?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

Let's say I have an iOS app that has a switch on a view controller.  I want to use this switch to alter a setting on the server side for the user.  So when the user flips the switch, I launch an asynchronous NSURLConnection to change the setting and the server responds to indicate the change was successful so that the app's UI reflects the change.  The view controller will have code to handle the response, but if the user changes view controllers after flipping the switch but before the response has come back, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1. Block the user by showing progress controller.
2. If you do not want to block the user, cancel the communication while deallocating the viewcontroller. If you do not want to close the communication, change the delegate object to some global object. This object will pass the notification once communication is comlpeted.

Answer (score 0):

NSURLConnection retains its delegate.  If the delegate is a view controller and the user navigates away from the view controller you may want to cancel the request and release it in the dealloc for view controller.  If you don't the view controller will not be deallocated until the connection succeeds or fails and calls the related delegate method on the view controller because the NSURLConnection will still have a strong reference to it.